# jQuery delay an animation time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I `onClick` I add a class to my container. When I select my button, I hide the content, add some transition to flip the container then display some info. Below is the code i'm using..

```
$('.btn-click').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('hidden');
  $('.card_container').delay('slow').toggleClass('class_active');
  $('.info').toggleClass('display');
});
```

and the styles for the class are:

```
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: .7s ease-in-out;
  background: black!important;
```

The issue is, the hide and show of `.content` class is too slow so I can see it before the `.card_container` has finished rotating. How can I delay the rotation. I tried `.deley('slow')` but didn't work?

I've added images below to show before & after,

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

---

### EDIT

So here's a fiddle for better understanding of my issue, sorry! https://jsfiddle.net/74vgvvhc/

As you can see, it a slight delay on the content (the text) when transitioning. I want the content to fade out, flip the card, then fade the other content in.

Comment: put your code in jsbin/fiddle pls!

Comment: Sorry, okay give me a few mins i'll make a fiddle! :) @Ajey

Comment: share your HTML/fiddle for better understanding mate

Comment: I'm using jade templating only reason I didn't add my HTML sorry! I've just updated with a jsFiddle that does exactly what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the info and card_active classes in a setTimeout after 700ms. This works, but isn't very elegant:

```js
$('.container').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.container').toggleClass('card_active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.info').toggleClass('display');
    $('.container').toggleClass('card_active');
  }, 700);
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: lime;
}
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.content {
  display: block;
}
.info {
  display: none;
}
.display {
  display: block;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.card_active {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: .7s ease-in-out;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <span class='content'>The content</span>
  <span class='info'>The info</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the class '.info' to '.display' after a delay of 700 milliseconds as you have given the transition time 'transition: .7s ease-in-out;' for '.card_active' in css.

```
$('.container').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.container').toggleClass('card_active');
  $('.info').delay(700).fadeToggle('display');
})
```

You can check the whole thing here https://jsfiddle.net/Rit_Design/eubrqnew/

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeToggle with a delay

```js
$('.container').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').toggleClass('hide');
  $('.container').toggleClass('card_active');
  $('.info').delay(500).fadeToggle('display');
})
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kjarriho/74vgvvhc/7/

Hopefully this helps!